# Track.form snippet from segment.io cancels redirect of the form

Tags: javascript, web, analytics, segment

After form submission, it has to redirect to another page:

`$("#formId").signUp({
APIUrl : 'https://website.com/api/register_user',
redirectUrl : 'staging'
});`

But, after I install track.form snippet in the footer, redirect is not working and page with form just reloads.

`var form = $('#formId');
analytics.trackForm(form, 'Signed Up Spanish', {
  email: document.email
});`

Answer (score 0):

See question and answer from Tim Macchi at https://forum.webflow.com/t/segment-trackform-interferes-with-form-behavior/67474

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( ".as-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    analytics.track('as masterclass signup', {
    }); 
  });
</script>
```